# drupal custom field in view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

i have a view with items and prices, each item has an id, another view taken from  a different content type also shows items and their base price the id of the item will be the same (basically one list is items containing seller prices and another is the market price, there can be many sellers but only one market price).

now i want to show in the first view a calculated field that will display the difference between the seller price (price of an item in first view) and the market price (the price of the item containing the same id in the second list).

is there a way to do it? if so how?

Comment: did you tried this pragmatically with views global php field?

Comment: @rafat so messing with the template file? is there a better way (im new to drupal and preffer the least complicated solution)